# Mixture of Windows (server) versions

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-server-2012

I'm preparing our windows server for a reinstall and tried to combine it with a version upgrade (still running 2008 without R2).

We are still not sure weather we should get 2008 R2 or the 2012 version.
All our clients are running Windows 7 and we aren't planning on switching to Windows 8 soon.
And our second domain controller is running the old Server 2008.

Should I expect issues regarding the version mixture?

- 1 server Windows Server 2012
- 1 server Windows Server 2008
- clients all windows 7

regards

Answer (score 8):

I can't imagine you having many problems with that setup, certainly being all-2012 may help with the W8 deployment but we use mixed environments and rarely if ever run into compatibility issues.

Answer (score 4):

There are no compatibility issues with Server 2012 and any other supports version of Windows. I would deploy 2012 wherever possible, since it is under support for longer than older versions of Windows. Other than FUD, there aren't many good reasons to not upgrade to 2012.

Comment: I can think of one good reason: Server 2012 R2.

Comment: If you need to deploy a server now, are you going to wait for an not-yet-released OS?